# How can I recover ubuntu ISO if I have only (all) files?

Tags: ubuntu, recovery

have remote VPS with ubuntu server 16.04. There is back up service in hosting company. But hosting company allow me download only files (all files in my VPS). How can I recover my VPS on Virtual Box on local computer if I have only ubuntu files ???

So, I have
bin, boot, etc, home, lib, lib64, media, mnt, opt, so on...
How can I recover it in my VBox ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=35735 It seems you will have to create first a guest OS on a DVI to copy your files to a second DVI. The above link is old, it should work with SATA controllers today.

You may install guest additions on the guest OS so you can copy the files to the guest through a shared folder, or you may create a third disk as a .vmdk file to allow raw access for the guest to a partition where you copy the files, with something like `sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ubuntupartition.vmdk -rawdisk /path/to/device -partitions number` Then use the guest OS to copy the files to the second DVI.

Then stop the VM, detach the second DVI, create a new Linux VM with that DVI, boot with EFI support (there should be an efi folder in Ubuntu files right ?). Maybe Ubuntu will complains with the partitions uuid and it will load recovery mode, from there edit fstab as necessary.

Hope this helps.